# JUnit Test Class failure test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In my program in the GradeBook Class i was supposed to add a toString method to the GradeBook class that returns a string with each score in scores separated by a space.

This i have done and when i create the JUnit Test i am supposed to Use the toString method to compare the contents of what is in the scores array vs. what is expected to be in the scores array and when i compile and run the JUnit Test the addScore test should be true.

the method we are to use is the assertTrue() method.
an ex. our teacher gave us was it should be in the form:

```
assertTrue(g1.toString.equals("50.0 75.0"); the 50 and 75 are scores taken from the objects of GradeBook made in the JUnit Test Class in the setUp() method but mine will be Totally different.
```

Now when i have compiled and run the prorgram the JUnit Test says there is an error in the 
    assertTrue() code but i don't see why.
Also i am positive that my toString is in the right form but if someone can shed light on my program i would appreciate it

GradeBook code is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GradeBook
{
private double[] scores;
private int scoresSize;

/**
  Constructs a gradebook with no scores and a given capacity.
  @capacity the maximum number of scores in this gradebook
 */
public GradeBook(int capacity)
{
    scores = new double[capacity];
    scoresSize = 0;
}

/**
  Adds a score to this gradebook.
  @param score the score to add
  @return true if the score was added, false if the gradebook is full
 */
public boolean addScore(double score)
{
    if (scoresSize < scores.length)
    {
        scores[scoresSize] = score;
        scoresSize++;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;      
}

/**
  Computes the sum of the scores in this gradebook.
  @return the sum of the scores
 */
public double sum()
{
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scoresSize; i++)
    {
        total = total + scores[i];
    }
    return total;
}

/**
  Gets the minimum score in this gradebook.
  @return the minimum score, or 0 if there are no scores.
 */
public double minimum()
{
    if (scoresSize == 0) return 0;
    double smallest = scores[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < scoresSize; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = scores[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

/**
  Gets the final score for this gradebook.
  @return the sum of the scores, with the lowest score dropped if 
  there are at least two scores, or 0 if there are no scores.
 */
public double finalScore() 
{
    if (scoresSize == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (scoresSize == 1)
        return scores[0];
    else
        return sum() - minimum();
}

public int getScoresSize() {
    return scoresSize;
}

public String toString(String scoreList){


    for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){

        scoreList += scores[i] + "";

    }
    return scoreList;
}

}
```

This the JUnit Test Class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class GradeBookTest {

private GradeBook g1;
private GradeBook g2;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    g1 = new GradeBook(5);
    g2 = new GradeBook(5);

    g1.addScore(45);
    g1.addScore(68);
    g1.addScore(35);
    g1.addScore(22);

    g2.addScore(99);
    g2.addScore(10);
    g2.addScore(77);
    g2.addScore(43);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    g1 = null;
    g2 = null;

}

@Test
public void testAddScore() {

    assertTrue(g1.toString().equals("45.0 68.0 35.0 22.0"));
    assertTrue(g2.toString().equals("99.0 10.0 77.0 43.0"));

    assertEquals(45,g1.getScoresSize(),.001);
    assertEquals(68,g1.getScoresSize(),.001);
    assertEquals(35,g1.getScoresSize(),.001);
    assertEquals(22,g1.getScoresSize(),.001);

    assertEquals(99,g2.getScoresSize(),.001);
    assertEquals(10,g2.getScoresSize(),.001);
    assertEquals(77,g2.getScoresSize(),.001);
    assertEquals(43,g2.getScoresSize(),.001);
}
```

Comment: Please add the compilation error.  It will make it much easier to diagnose your problem if we know what your problem is.

Comment: Your GradeBook::toString expects a scoreList string as an argument. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @atk
The error says:
 java.lang.AssertionError at GradeBookTest.testAddScore(GradeBookTest.java:41)

Then when i click on it, it highlights the assertTrue code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toString method has a signature:

```
public String toString(String scoreList)
```

it requires parameter and you invoke it just like:

```
g1.toString()
```

Change your toString method to:

```
public String toString(){

    String scoreList = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){

        scoreList += scores[i] + " "; //remember to add a space here!

    }
    return scoreList;
}
```

Comment: I changed my string method but the same error appears.

the error says:
java.lang.AssertionError
at GradeBookTest.testAddScore(GradeBookTest.java:41

Comment: Now this is different error. It says that your code is OK, but test function returns a different value in line 41. Which one is line 41 in your code ?

Comment: Actually you should remove those zeros from "45.0 68.0 35.0 22.0" (it should be: "45 68 35 22 ") (there is a one space problem) - see updated reply

Comment: It was the assertTrue(g1.toString().equals("45.0 68.0 35.0 22.0"));

even after i remove the zeros the error still shows up

Comment: This is the form the professor showed us to use but now i don't know why it's not working

yeah i added a space in the quotes in the for loop

Comment: But be careful - do you want to have a space after the last element?

Comment: Yes there should be a space after the last element

Comment: ... Ok, what you got now?

Comment: uhhh the same error, i'll have to ask my professor about this because i just can't see why this shouldn't be True for comparing the scores array in the toString method and AddScore method

Comment: I'm your professor today lol :P Do you have toString() method as in my post and result as: "45 68 35 22 " <- look for a additional space at the end. And remember to tweak you second assert similarly. Also your asserts like assertEquals(45,g1.getScoresSize(),.001); doesn't make sanse, as you comparing array length, not actual score value.

Comment: Yeah i had that but same error mistake appears
lol for the assertEquals() method:

we are supposed to compare the scoreSize to the expected number of scores entered
That's why you see it like that

Comment: Hi, I've pasted the code to Eclipse to try it - there are multiple errors: g1.toString() returns: "45.0 68.0 35.0 22.0 0.0 ", so you have initalized it with capacity of 5, but there are only 4 elements, and last one is 0.0 BTW: you need those zeros apparently (sorry, my bad). So, you need to: 1. change expected result to: "45.0 68.0 35.0 22.0 0.0 " 2. init GradeBook with 4: g1 = new GradeBook(4); g2 = new GradeBook(4); 3. to test Score size you need assert like this: assertEquals(4, g1.getScoresSize());   assertEquals(4, g2.getScoresSize());

Comment: But you will probably need to change your implementation - instead of immutable array you should use dynamic collection like List (ArrayList), so you dont have problems with GradeBook size (it could be any size, without init param)

Comment: Ohh okay i see my problem now, thank you so much it was checking if the size matched exactly how many scores i entered for each GradeBook object created.

Worked perfectly thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

just spotted this... common mistake...

```
g1.toString.equals(...)
```

should be

```
g1.toString().equals(....)
```

Note the additional parenthesis after toString - toString is a method and needs to be called.

Comment: yeah i already had the parenthesis after toString from before

Comment: @user2807804: in that case, please update your question with the correct syntax that you are using.

Comment: why the down vote?  Does someone not believe that you need to use parenthesis in Java to call a toString() method?